# Appear to have free space but no space left error message

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage, docker, user-space

Attempting to load a local docker image :

```
 docker load -i 3.tar
bc224b1b676d: Loading layer 196.9 MB/196.9 MB
53edc9780c07: Loading layer 209.9 kB/209.9 kB
738d3f35b582: Loading layer 7.168 kB/7.168 kB
4375cecd293e: Loading layer 4.608 kB/4.608 kB
4fcb79d431cc: Loading layer 3.072 kB/3.072 kB
f7bcedf6de2a: Loading layer 22.37 MB/22.37 MB
4c0d3636cee0: Loading layer 42.95 MB/42.95 MB
b20e0c295384: Loading layer 22.37 MB/22.37 MB
757a4c7cfb9e: Loading layer 8.596 MB/8.596 MB
69158f9f7eaf: Loading layer 154.9 MB/154.9 MB
e8a81197c9e7: Loading layer 2.484 MB/2.484 MB
c55e234b44df: Loading layer 2.423 MB/2.423 MB
3f49a40557bb: Loading layer 2.838 MB/2.838 MB
e7ce4a45b0e9: Loading layer 838.1 kB/838.1 kB
78956c751b68: Loading layer 22.39 MB/22.39 MB
96f679c7fb3a: Loading layer  2.78 MB/2.78 MB
f7bb8848b7c2: Loading layer 228.4 MB/569.7 MB
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar: no space left on device
```

Checking specific drive the error is reported on :

```
df --block-size=GB /usr/lib/
Filesystem     1GB-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0            12GB   2GB      10GB  15% /
```

There also appears to be adequate free space on the drive :

```
df
Filesystem                1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                       16401756       4   16401752   1% /dev
tmpfs                       3288160     284    3287876   1% /run
/dev/dm-0                  11677616 1593444    9467932  15% /
none                              4       0          4   0% /sys/fs/hgr
none                           5120       0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                      16440796       0   16440796   0% /run/shm
none                         102400       0     102400   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vglocal-tmp     3869352    7808    3645276   1% /tmp
/dev/xvda1                   236876   88299     132040  41% /boot
/dev/mapper/vglocal-fisc    5771200   11708    5443284   1% /fisc
/dev/mapper/vglocal-home    3869352    7968    3645116   1% /home
/dev/mapper/vglocal-opt     3869352  192748    3460336   6% /opt
/dev/mapper/vglocal-var     3869352 1626212    2026872  45% /var
/dev/mapper/vglocal-tmq     3869352 1195688    2457396  33% /devel/tmq
/dev/mapper/vglocal-log     3869352   35980    3617104   1% /var/log
/dev/xvdb1               1968487228 1580756 1866890088   1% /my-drive
```

It appears I do have adequate space ?

I've attempted to clean the drive using `sudo apt-get clean` and other methods referenced from [What's the good way to clean up the system (and is Bleachbit safe) on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657091/whats-the-good-way-to-clean-up-the-system-and-is-bleachbit-safe-on-ubuntu-14) but same error.

I've also tried `df -i` referenced from [Disk has free space, but none available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855195/disk-has-free-space-but-none-available) :

```
udev                       4100439   459   4099980    1% /dev
tmpfs                      4110199   428   4109771    1% /run
/dev/dm-0                   750720 94870    655850   13% /
none                       4110199    13   4110186    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       4110199     2   4110197    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      4110199     1   4110198    1% /run/shm
none                       4110199     3   4110196    1% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vglocal-tmp     249984    13    249971    1% /tmp
/dev/xvda1                   62248   304     61944    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/vglocal-fisc    375360    12    375348    1% /fisc
/dev/mapper/vglocal-home    249984    52    249932    1% /home
/dev/mapper/vglocal-opt     249984 14131    235853    6% /opt
/dev/mapper/vglocal-var     249984 42457    207527   17% /var
/dev/mapper/vglocal-tmq     249984 11091    238893    5% /fisc/tmq
/dev/mapper/vglocal-log     249984    94    249890    1% /var/log
/dev/xvdb1               125001728    12 125001716    1% /my-drive
```

Alternatively I create a new mounted disk how can I point all install files to point at this new disk ?

How can I free space in order to install the docker container ?

Update :

Size of tar file :

```
ls -l --block-size=GB 3.tar
-rw------- 1 a511381 users 2GB Jan 26 23:55 3.tar
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think unpacked it's approx 3GB .

Checking size of /tmp :

```
df --block-size=GB /tmp
Filesystem              1GB-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vglocal-tmp        4GB   1GB       4GB   1% /tmp
```

Comment: How big is that tar file packed and unpacked ? Some programs use /tmp to unpack temporary files. Your /tmp might be the problem here.

Comment: @albertj please see update

Comment: Can you try with a different tmp dir, and then unmount your /tmp partition ? See e.g. here for more info : https://serverfault.com/questions/72955/how-to-change-default-tmp-to-home-user-tmp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435062/what-happened-to-the-tmp-environment-variable https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables